# onActivityResult doesn't call for getting response in AppAuth library

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth, authorization, appauth

I use **AppAuth** library(https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) for oauth authorization code flow. I do everything step by step from the Read.me. Now I can see the **login page** but after login I will be transferred to redirect page and stay there and browser doesn't close and **onActivityResult** never call.
(I use navigation component(single activity) and I put onActivityResult in one of my Fragment)
what should I do?

```
private val loginLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(TAG, "loginLauncher: $result")
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            viewModel.endLogin(result.data!!)
        }
    }
```

**but it's never called**
and this is my manifest:

```
   <activity
            android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="myPackageName"
                    android:path="/oauth2redirect"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

what should I set for host,path and scheme ?

Now I need get code from redirectUrl and do authorization and send response to my fragment(I think this library support them but not working for me)

Answer (score 0):

### When Using the Web Flow

The `android:host` needs to be a real domain, not your package name.

Change this:

```xml
android:host="myPackageName"
```

to this:

```xml
android:host="app.domain.com"
```

If after the user gives consent to your app you get an error in the browser that looks like this:

```
 cannot GET /oauth2redirect
```

Then configure AppAuth to always prompt the user to select the OAuth account he wants to use:

```java
AuthorizationRequest.Builder authRequestBuilder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
        Objects.requireNonNull(authState.getAuthorizationServiceConfiguration()),
        clientId,
        ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
        Uri.parse(redirectUri))
        .setScope(authScope)
        .setPrompt("select_account");
```

The web flow requires the use of a `client_secret` in the mobile app, what is not advised due to security concerns, thus you may want to use instead the Mobile flow.

### Using the Mobile Flow

For the mobile flow you don't need to set the the `host and the` path`, therefore your activity intent should look like this:

```xml
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    tools:node="replace"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

         <data android:scheme="com.domain.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Bear in mind that exists a slight difference on how you perform the request when using the web or the mobile flow:

```java
private void startCodeExchange() {
    Log.i(TAG, "---> Starting code exchange");

    loginListener.onEvent(AuthRepo.this, AUTH_CODE_EXCHANGE_START);

    AuthorizationResponse resp = authState.getLastAuthorizationResponse();

    // performWebFlowTokenRequest(resp);
    performMobileFlowTokenRequest(resp);
}

private void performMobileFlowTokenRequest(AuthorizationResponse resp) {
    if (resp != null) {
        authService.performTokenRequest(
                resp.createTokenExchangeRequest(), this::onTokenRequestCompleted);
    }
}

private void performWebFlowTokenRequest(AuthorizationResponse resp) {
    ClientAuthentication clientAuth = new ClientSecretPost(app.getString(R.string.client_secret));

    if (resp != null) {
        authService.performTokenRequest(
                resp.createTokenExchangeRequest(), clientAuth, this::onTokenRequestCompleted);
    }
}
```

This [code examples](https://github.com/approov/AppAuth-OAuth2-Approov/blob/e8f826d336062dd23318768aab222ae2ced38ba7/android/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/auth/demo/auth/AuthRepo.java#L318) have been extracted from [this branch](https://github.com/approov/AppAuth-OAuth2-Approov/tree/dev_runtime-secrets) of a repo I am currently working on for a series of articles on securing OAuth2 on mobile.